# Convert spring endpoint output

Tags: java, spring, converters

I have a couple of endpoints that return instances of class *A*, but I wish to convert their output to another class *B* **without modifying the methods.**

I have researched the topic of spring converters and how they can be applied to format input path variables or paramaters and convert them to other classes, but I cannot find a way of converting the output of endpoints.

Can it be done with converters? Or am I missing a better existing solution?

Comment: what is the reason for not directly modifying the endpoint methods? I mean what are you trying to accomplish not only from technical perspective.

Comment: From pure technical perspective Interceptors could be used to achieve your goal.

Comment: I want to be able to encrypt certain properties for some dtos, and I want this to be decoupled so it can be separately configured on different product instalations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `JsonSerializer`. This serializer takes an instance of `A` and instead of serializing it, create an instance of `B`, generates the corresponding JSON representation, and sends this JSON to the client.

```
@JsonComponent
public final class MyJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(A a, JsonGenerator jsonGen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        B b = new B();
        jsonGenerator.writeObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help @Marcus!!

Comment: Just for reference, the parent class is StdSerializer<T>